# Checking balance of a travel card with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

A Leap Card is essentially a travel card for Dublin, Ireland that can be used to pay for a bus or tram fare. It has to be topped up and I often forget how much I have left on it.

To get familiar with Selenium, I wrote some code that gets the balance for me. I haven't worked with this framework before, so I'd like to know if there's room for improvement here.

```
import json

from selenium import webdriver


def get_credentials():
    """Get user credentials from a JSON file"""
    with open('auth.json', 'r') as f:
        auth = json.load(f)
        username = auth['username']
        password = auth['password']
    return username, password


class LeapHandler:
    """Class to handle any interactions with Leap Card website"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get('https://www.leapcard.ie/en/login.aspx')
        self.login()

    def get_login_elements(self):
        """Find and return elements necessary to log in"""
        username_id = 'ContentPlaceHolder1_UserName'
        password_id = 'ContentPlaceHolder1_Password'
        login_id = 'ContentPlaceHolder1_btnlogin'
        username_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id(username_id)
        password_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id(password_id)
        login_button = self.driver.find_element_by_id(login_id)
        return username_field, password_field, login_button

    def login(self):
        """Login into user account"""
        username_field, password_field, login = self.get_login_elements()
        username, password = get_credentials()
        username_field.send_keys(username)
        password_field.send_keys(password)
        login.click()

    def get_balance(self):
        """Return current Leap Card Balance"""
        balance = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.pull-left').text
        return balance

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lh = LeapHandler()
    balance = lh.get_balance()
    print(f'LepaCard balance is €{balance}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually quite clean and readable, good job. Here are some of the things I would consider changing:

- you can simplify `get_credentials()` a bit, using the tuple packing/unpacking:

  ```
  def get_credentials():
      """Get user credentials from a JSON file."""
      with open('auth.json', 'r') as f:
          auth = json.load(f)
          return auth['username'], auth['password']
  ```
- end your docstrings with a dot [as per PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id33)
- if the page manipulation selenium code is going to continue grow, you should definitely consider switching to using [Page Object pattern](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html) building abstractions around the webpages you are working with. But, for this kind of problem, it is perfectly fine to not use page objects
- `div.pull-left` does not look like a good quality locator. It may work now, but this locator is fragile because it is design-specific (`pull-left` is a bootstrap class used for page layout). See if this element has an `id` or a data-oriented `class` or a data-oriented attribute.

Comment: Using the `div.pull-left` locator is a workaround, as I couldn't get the text any other way. Here is the snippet from page source: https://pastebin.com/Z3Kec3zD

Comment: @LukaszSalitra right, not the easiest markup to deal with. I would probably use a preceding label with, for example, an XPath - something like: `//div[contains(label/@id, "TravelCreditBalance")]/following-sibling::div/div` - not the simplest expression though. Looking at that, your workaround looks better, doesn't it? :)

Comment: Objectively, it does! :) But as you said, it is fragile and perhaps not the best. I wanted to get going with XPath either way, so I'm sure that will give me a right idea! Thanks for the review, thoughtful as always.